# How to convert js code based on promise to async/await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I have a js code based on a promise like this:

```
fetch(answerUrl, bodyRequest)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
     data['status'] === 200 ? indicateSuccess() : indicateError();
  })
  .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
```

if I want to change it to async/await, is this correct way?

```
async function answerUrlData(answerUrl, bodyRequest) {
  try {
    const response = await fecth(answerUrl, bodyRequest)
    const data = await response.json()
    return data['status'] === 200 ? indicateSuccess() : indicateError();
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The  `await data['status'] === 200 ? indicateSuccess() : indicateError();` line is wrong, the  `await` is useless, but I'm not sure of the exact goal here. You seem to mix concerns.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Both your examples are actually not good examples of promises. Why do you couple the code with external functions `indicateSuccess` and `indicateError`? Promises already have those cases built-in. Instead you should just call the overall function and use `then` or `catch` (or `await` and `try/catch`).

Comment: @DenysSéguret I have changed my code, please check again, is that the right way?
my goal here is to divide the code into another function to use in the previous function

Comment: @str because `indicateSuccess` and `indicateError` have other functions, so I don't use catch or try catch here

Comment: @Quentin ok thanks for your advice